# How to add two columns of a Stata/CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with two columns (permno_adj and publn_year) and I want to combine them but don't know how to do it.

**The code I am using:**

```
patents = pd.read_csv('E:/Work/file.csv')

patents = patents[['publn_nr', 'permno_adj', 'publn_year', 'IPC1']].dropna().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
patents = patents[(patents['publn_year'] >= 1980) & (patents['publn_year'] < 2016)].reset_index(drop=True)

print(patents)
```

**The output I am currently getting i:**

```
         publn_nr permno_adj  publn_year  IPC1
0            1830    US4060B        2005  F16F
1           24429    US4060A        2004  B29C
2           24943     US1794        2006  C08J
3           26115  US133366B        1999  A61B
4           31737    US4060A        2004  C08F
```

The output I am looking for is something like "US4060B2005"

Comment: `patents['new_col'] = patents['permno_adj']+patents['publn_year'].astype(str)`

Comment: The fact that this file may have come from or been near Stata is irrelevant to what you are asking so far as I can see. Hence tag removed.

Comment: @NickCox yes you are right. I had the same file in 2 formats state and CSV. I will edit my question. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate like string

```py
patents['new_column'] = patents['permno_adj'].astype(str) + patents['publn_year'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Welcome @Gaju_masare :) Happy Learning !!!

Answer (score 1):

follow `assign` function [pandas assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```py
d = {'col1': ['c11', 'c12'], 'col2': ['c21', 'c22']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.assign(col3=df['col1'] + df['col2'])
df
  col1 col2    col3
0  c11  c21  c11c21
1  c12  c22  c12c22
```